# Ruby on Rails routes translation using route_translator gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, routes

I'm using the route_translator gem and when I run `rake routes` it seems to be working fine.
This is part of the output:

```
travels_en    GET    /en/travels(.:format)  travels#index {:locale=>"en"}
travels_pt_br GET    /viagens(.:format)     travels#index {:locale=>"pt-BR"}
```

I can access the pt-BR routes but all my application links will take me to the english route, I'm only using rails methods.
Do I have to change the route methods like `new_travel_path` and `link_to` to something specific?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you need to do is make sure the pt_br YML file has the foreign routes you want to appear. For example in your pt_br YML file you would have the following code to match your example:

```
  routes:
    travels: viagens
```

When you click **en** you should see `/en/travels` as before. When you click **pt_br** you should see `/pt_br/viagens`.

Another thing to check is to make sure that in `config/routes.rb` that you have the routes being translated within the following statement.

```
localized do
  whatever your routes are should appear here
end
```

This is what I have done with one of my sites that is in English and French.